# Winforms Document Manager Using Filesystem & SQL Database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to create a document manager for my winforms application.  It is not web-based.

I would like to be able to allow users to "attach" documents to various entities (personnel, companies, work orders, tasks, batch parts etc) in my application.

After lots of research I have made the decision to use the file system to store the files instead of a blob in SQL.  I will set up a folder to store all the files, but I will store the document information (filepath, uploaded by, changed by, revision etc) in parent-child relationship with the entity in an sql database.

I only want users to be able to work with the documents through the application to prevent the files and database records getting out of sync.  I some how need to protect the document folder from normal users but at the same time allow the application to work with it. My original thoughts were to set the application up with the only username and password with access to the folder and use impersonation to login to the folder and work with the files.  From feedback in a recent thread I started I now believe this was not a good idea, and working with impersonation has been a headache.

I also thought about using a webservice but some of our clients just run the application on there laptops with no windows server.  Most are using windows server or citrix/windows server.

What would be the best way to set this up so that only the application handles the documents?

Comment: Just to clear up the requirements.  Is the application on a different computer than the SQL Server?  Or are they both on the same box?

Comment: The application is on a seperate computer to that of SQL server.

Comment: Did you consider looking at a content management server (CMS) for this?

Comment: No I hadnt, I have no experience with these, do you have some examples that would suit?

Comment: I have some experience working on a project where we kept info for files in a db, and the files themselves in a filesystem repository. There were a bunch of cases on the synchronization between the db and the filesystem, lots of transactional processing and much more. The main problems were related to the availability of the repository and the access rights that the app uses (in our case it was a shared repo in a local intranet of an organization).We had problems with timestamps in db and network paths (IP or domain name). Anyway we managed to fix these but it was a troublesome taks. Good luck

Comment: Great something to look forward too!  Care to share some code? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with these options, in no particular order.

1. Create a folder on the server that's not accessible to users.  Have a web service running on the server (either using IIS, or standalone WCF app) that has a method to upload & download files.  Your web service should manage the directory where the files are being stored.  The SQL database should have all the necessary metadata to find the documents.  In this manner, only your app can get access to these files.  Thus the users could only see the docs via the app.
2. I can see that you chose to store the documents on the file system.  I wrote a similar system (e.g. attachments to customers/orders/sales people/etc...) except that I am storing it in SQL Server.  It actually works pretty well.  I initially worried that so much data is going to slowdown the database, but that turned out to be not the case.  It's working great.  The only advice I can give if you take this route is to create a separate database for all your attachments.  Why?  Because if you want to get a copy of the RDBMS for your local testing, you do not want to be copying a 300GB database that's made up of 1GB of actual data and 299GB of attachments.
3. You mentioned that some of your users will be carrying laptops.  In that case, they might not be connected to the LAN.  If that is the case, I'd consider storing the files (and maybe metadata itself) in the cloud (EC2, Azure, Rackspace, etc...).

Comment: excellent reply - thanks. Option1 (looks the best) - how would you maintain synchronization with the database? And if used in an intranet environment, will the webservice have to go over the net?  Some clients have poor internet connections.  Option2 - Thats is by far the easiest option and I would have preferred it BUT I choose the file system as some clients are using SQL Express limited to 4gb.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Reafidy Q: How would you maintain synchronization with the database?  A: The upload method on your web service would have to save the metadata to the database.  And since you are accessing the web service from a WinForms app, you are in full control.  Q: If used in an intranet environment, will the webservice have to go over the net.  A: No. Web Service does not mean going over the web.  It will be routed by your internal router straight to the server.

Answer (score 3):

I know you said you read about blobs but are you aware of the FILESTREAM options in SQL Server 2008 and onwards? Basically rather than saving blobs into your database which isn't always a good idea you can instead save the blobs to the NTFS file system using transactional NTFS. This to me sounds like exactly what you are trying to achieve.

All the file access security would be handled through SQL server (as it would be the only thing needing access to the folder) and you don't need to write your own logic for adding and removing files from the file system. To remove a file from the file system you just delete the related record in the sql server table and it handles removing it from the file system.

See:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

Comment: Thanks Pete,  yes that is a great idea and I had looked into it myself but unfortunately some of our clients are using SQL 2005.  A shame because that solution is perfect for us.

Comment: Also, it requires windows authentication and does not allow sql authentication which our application uses.  Thanks though.

Comment: I hadn't realized about the Windows Authentication requirement to be honest as we use it. Seems like a bit of a flaw if wanting to use it for the web. There seems to be work arounds such as using ASP.NET impersonation http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/03/16/saving-and-retrieving-file-using-filestream-sql-server-2008.aspx and http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/416460/sql-server-authentication-filestream Just adding this for anyone else who looks at this question.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 (Easy): Security through Obscurity

Give everyone read (and write as appropriate) access to your document directories. Save your document 'path' as the full URI (\\servername\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.ext) so that your users can access the files, but they're not immediately available if someone goes wandering through their mapped drives.

Option 2 (Harder): Serve the File from SQL Server

You can use either a CLR function or SQLDMO to read the file from disk, present it as a varbinary field and reconstruct it at the client side. Upside is that your users will see a copy, not the real thing; makes viewing safer, editing and saving harder.

Enjoy! ;-)

Comment: Thanks Steve,RE: option1, Im not sure how that works.  If the users have read & write access to the document directory wont it appear in the file explorer?  RE: Option 2, looks like a good option, never heard of either CLR or SQLDMO, from my reading SQLDMO wont be available in next version of SQL so I think I'll avoid using it.  Had a look at CLR,  I think you meaning something like: http://filesystemhelper.codeplex.com/? Would I have to give SQL Server permission to access the document directory?  All out, I still feel there must be an easier way!

Comment: I have thoroughly researched CLR it seems to have its advantages and I can execute the whole process of updating the database and uploading the files in one.  However I am cautious about the deployment process, should I expect to see resistance from DBA with regard to security etc...